# Spark 1.3.1 mapping data to key-value[] pair in Java

Tags: apache-spark, mapping

I have flat file with the following structure:

```
key1|"value-001"
key2|"value-002"
key2|"value-003"
key3|"value-004"
key2|"value-005"
key1|"value-006"
key3|"value-007"
```

I need to map this data file to key-value pairs where value will be list of values for one key, such as:

```
key1:["value-001","value-006"]
key2:["value-002","value-003","value-005"]
key3:["value-004","value-007"]
```

I need do this from Java code. As I understood from Spark Programming Guide this operation should be implemented by `sc.flatMapValues(..)`, `sc.flatMap(..)` or `sc.groupByKey(..)` but I don't know which one. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `reduceByKey`:) This list imitates your input:

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList(
  new String[]{new String("key1|value-001"),
               new String("key2|value-002"),
               new String("key2|value-003"),
               new String("key3|value-004"),
               new String("key2|value-005"),
               new String("key1|value-006"),
               new String("key3|value-007")});
```

Converting to rdd (you will of course just read in your file with `sc.textFile()`)

```
JavaRDD<String> rdd = javaSparkContext.parallelize(input);
```

We now have an RDD of strings. The following maps to key-value pairs (note the value is being added to a list) and then `reduceByKey` combines all values for each key into a list, yielding the result you want.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, List<String>> keyValuePairs = rdd.mapToPair(obj -> {
        String[] split = obj.split("|");
        return new Tuple2(split[0], Arrays.asList(new String[]{split[1]}));
    });

JavaPairRDD<String, List<String>> result = keyValuePairs.reduceByKey((v1, v2) -> {
        v1.addAll(v2);
        return v1;
    });
```

EDIT: I feel I should mention that you could also use a `groupByKey`. However, you usually want to favor `reduceByKey` over `groupByKey` because `reduceByKey` does a map-side reduce BEFORE shuffling the data around, whereas `groupByKey` shuffles everything around. In your particular case, you will probably end up shuffling the same amount of data around as with a `groupByKey` since you want all values to be gathered, but using `reduceByKey` is just a better habit to be in :)

Comment: Glad to hear it :) Can you mark it as "Answered" then?

Comment: np, if can find this option :)