# How to process Map<Key,value > in spark?

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, apache-spark, bigdata

I am new to Spark programming and I am trying to find out the number of times that a string occurs in a file against a key.
Here is my input like this:

```
-------------
2017-04-13 15:56:57.147::ProductSelectPanel::1291::PRODUCT_SALE_ENTRY::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0008::CROCIN 120MG 60ML SYP::5::0::
2017-04-13 15:57:01.008::ProductSelectPanel::1599::PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0008::CROCIN 120MG 60ML SYP::4::1::1013065197
2017-04-13 15:57:09.182::ProductSelectPanel::1118::ALTERNATIVE_PRODUCT_ENTRY::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0005::CROCIN 500MG TAB::0
2017-04-13 15:57:15.153::ProductSelectPanel::1121::NO_STOCK_PRODUCT::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0005::CROCIN 500MG TAB::0::0::
2017-04-13 15:57:19.696::ProductSelectPanel::1118::ALTERNATIVE_PRODUCT_ENTRY::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0005::CROCIN 500MG TAB::0
2017-04-13 15:57:23.190::ProductSelectPanel::1291::PRODUCT_SALE_ENTRY::INAPHYD00124::1::CALP0005::CALPOL 500MG TAB::110::0::
2017-04-13 15:56:57.147::ProductSelectPanel::1291::PRODUCT_SALE_ENTRY::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0008::CROCIN 120MG 60ML SYP::5::0::
2017-04-13 15:57:01.008::ProductSelectPanel::1599::PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0008::CROCIN 120MG 60ML SYP::4::1::1013065197
2017-04-13 15:57:09.182::ProductSelectPanel::1118::ALTERNATIVE_PRODUCT_ENTRY::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0005::CROCIN 500MG TAB::0
2017-04-13 15:57:15.153::ProductSelectPanel::1121::NO_STOCK_PRODUCT::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0005::CROCIN 500MG TAB::0::0::
2017-04-13 15:57:19.696::ProductSelectPanel::1118::ALTERNATIVE_PRODUCT_ENTRY::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0005::CROCIN 500MG TAB::0
2017-04-13 15:57:23.190::ProductSelectPanel::1291::PRODUCT_SALE_ENTRY::INAPHYD00124::1::CALP0005::CALPOL 500MG TAB::110::0::
2017-04-13 15:56:57.147::ProductSelectPanel::1291::PRODUCT_SALE_ENTRY::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0008::CROCIN 120MG 60ML SYP::5::0::
2017-04-13 15:57:01.008::ProductSelectPanel::1599::PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0008::CROCIN 120MG 60ML SYP::4::1::1013065197
2017-04-13 15:57:09.182::ProductSelectPanel::1118::ALTERNATIVE_PRODUCT_ENTRY::INAPHYD00124::1::CROC0005::CROCIN 500MG TAB::0
.......
```

My Spark program is like this.

```
final Function<String, List<String>> LINE_MAPPER=new Function<String, List<String>>() {

            @Override
            public List<String> call(String line) throws Exception {
                String[] lineArary=line.split("::");
                return Arrays.asList(lineArary[3],lineArary[6]);
            }
        };
        final PairFunction<String, String, Integer> word_paper=new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String word) throws Exception {

                return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(word, Integer.valueOf(1));
            }
        };
        JavaRDD<List<String>> javaRDD =lineRDD.map(LINE_MAPPER);


After doing map transformation  i am getting like this:

[[PRODUCT_SALE_ENTRY,CROC0008],[NO_STOCK_PRODUCT,CROC0005],[NO_STOCK_PRODUCT,CROC0005],[PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE,CROC0008],[PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE,CROC0005],[PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE,CROC003],....]

but i want the result like..
[[NO_STOCK_PRODUCT,[CROC0005,4]],[PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE,[CROC0008,2]],[PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE,[CROC0005,1]],....]
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thank you DNA, Its works great.
finally my code like that:

JavaPairRDD<String, String> keyValuePairs = lineRDD.mapToPair(obj -> {
            String[] split = obj.split("::");
            return new Tuple2<String, String>(split[3],split[6]);
        });

         JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String, String>, Integer> newRFDD=keyValuePairs.mapToPair(obj -> {
            return new Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, Integer>(new Tuple2<>(obj._1, obj._2),1);
        });
         JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String, String>, Integer> result = newRFDD.reduceByKey((v1, v2) -> {
                return v1+v2;
            });
         result.map(f->{ return f._1._2()+"\t"+f._2()+"\t"+f._1._1(); }).saveAsTextFile("file:///home/charan/offlinefiles/result");
         System.out.println("result :"+result.take(10));

and output would be:

CROC0005    620 NO_STOCK_PRODUCT
CROC2107    15  PRODUCT_SALE_ENTRY
CROC2120    7   NO_STOCK_PRODUCT
CROC0229    2   NO_STOCK_PRODUCT
CROC0009    1   NO_STOCK_PRODUCT
CROC0005    1250    ALTERNATIVE_PRODUCT_ENTRY
CROC2302    2   ALTERNATIVE_PRODUCT_ENTRY
CROC2807    5   PRODUCT_SALE_ENTRY
CROC0213    2   ALTERNATIVE_PRODUCT_ENTRY
CROC20221 18    ALTERNATIVE_PRODUCT_ENTRY.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to treat each key+string pair as a composite key, and count the number of occurrences of that composite key.

You can do something like this by using `countByValue()` (see the [JavaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#countByValue())). However, as the documentation says:

> Note that this method should only be used if the resulting map is
>   expected to be small, as the whole thing is loaded into the driver's
>   memory. To handle very large results, consider using rdd.map(x => (x,
>   1L)).reduceByKey(_ + _)...

So, just `map` each of your values (such as `[PRODUCT_SALE_ENTRY,CROC0008]` to a pair of the form  ((PRODUCT_SALE_ENTRY,CROC0008), 1L), then `reduceByKey()` (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091091/apache-spark-reducebykey-java)).

I've only done this in Scala, not Java - I think you may need to use `mapToPair()` e.g. as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861170/spark-1-3-1-mapping-data-to-key-value-pair-in-java). This will give an RDD of the form:

```
((NO_STOCK_PRODUCT,CROC0005), 4),
((PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE,CROC0008), 2),
((PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE,CROC0005), 1),
...
```

which is close to what you asked for.

Comment: After maptoPair i am getting output as:

Comment: After maptoPair i am getting output as:[(ALTERNATIVE_PRODUCT_ENTRY,[CROC0005]), (NO_STOCK_PRODUCT,[CROC0005]), (PRODUCT_SALE_ENTRY,[CROC0008]), (PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE,[CROC0008])]
my code:JavaPairRDD<String, List<String>> javapRDD=lineRDD.mapToPair(obj -> {
         String[] split = obj.split("::");
         return new Tuple2(split[3], Arrays.asList(new String[]{split[6]}));
     });

Comment: How can get this

Comment: How can i get this :((NO_STOCK_PRODUCT,CROC0005), 4),
((PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE,CROC0008), 2),
((PRODUCT_SALE_WITH_BARCODE,CROC0005), 1),
...